# Circular reference detected for service "kernel.listener.your_listener_name",

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-3.3

I added the following lines in my **services.yml**

```
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    # automatically injects dependencies in your services
    autowire: true
    # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    autoconfigure: true
    # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
    # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
    #public: false
```

When run the following command **./bin/console cach:clear**, I received the following error :

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]                                                                              
  Circular reference detected for service "kernel.listener.your_listener_name", path: "kernel.listener.your_listener_name -> kernel.listener.your_listener_name".
```

For information, this is the definition of the service :

```
kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
    class: DEL\Bundle\ApiBundle\Exception\ApiException
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

and here is the service 's class :

```
<?php

namespace DEL\Bundle\ApiBundle\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ApiException extends HttpException
{
    public function __construct($statusCode = 0, $message = null, \Exception $previous = null, array $headers = array(), $code = 0)
    {
        parent::__construct($statusCode, $message, $previous, $headers, $code);
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($exception instanceof APIExceptionInterface) {
            $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
            $error = $xml->addChild('error');
            $error->addChild('id', $exception::ID);
            $error->addChild('error', $exception::GLOBAL_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            $error->addChild('message', $exception->getMessage());
            $message = $xml->asXML();
            // Customize your response object to display the exception details
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setContent($message);
            // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
            // holds status code and header details
            if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
                $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
                $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
            } else {
                $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            // Send the modified response object to the event
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

So is there a solution to this problem please ?

Comment: Possibly because you are trying to inject an exception into an exception?  But more importantly, which are you trying to make an exception a listener?  Does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: @Cerad I make  a migration to symfony 3.4, so it's a legacy code and i'd like to apply the autowiring and the problem  is that "ApiException" extends the parent class "HttpException"

Comment: But why does it extend an exception?  Makes no sense.  I don't see where any thing from the parent class is even used though maybe there is more code that is not posted.  Change ApiException to ApiListener and get rid of the constructor.  It should work just fine.  Maybe you need an ApiException elsewhere in your code but you certainly don't need it to be a listener.

Comment: Curious if you got this sorted out.  I was thinking of posting a more detailed example but I don't have a working 3.4 app to test against.  If you really wanted to minimize changes then just supply the arguments manually and things should work as before.